# Enums don't equal on different machines?

Tags: c#, enums, wix

I'm using the Wix `Bootstrapper` Enum `LaunchAction`:

```
Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.LaunchAction
```

On my machine, a different laptop and a virtual machine when I do:

```
var m_state = LaunchAction.Install;
```

And then later on:

```
if(m_state == LaunchAction.Install)
```

It passes. Looking in the debugger m_state has the value Install. However on my colleagues machine the if statement does not pass. Looking in the debugger the values are exactly the same. My thoughts are that he might have an outdated / updated version of the `WixBootstrapper` DLL however that shouldn't actually have any effect because it would use that DLL when compiling.

Edit:

Comparing them as `int` values, on my machine and the laptop both values are `5`. On my colleagues machine `m_state` is `5` and `LaunchAction.Install` is `4`.

Edit 2:

So what we believe is happening is that the DLL he has on his machine is from the Wix toolset 3.9 whilst the other machines are using 3.10. In 3.9 the `LaunchAction.Install` is 4, whereas in 3.10 it is 5.

The custom bootstrapper has this DLL as a payload file. What we think has happened is that the payload file being added is a 3.10 version but when its originally compiled it's using the 3.9. Resulting the in the comparison being:

```
if(m_state == 4)
```

The answer being false because the value of m_state is using the 3.10 version so it reads 5.

Comment: If you cast the value to an `int`, what are the two values? Also, are you sure your debugger has the right code version running? That might cause line number offset.

Answer (score 0):

You must rebuild bootstrapper applications and bundles when you switch versions of WiX. They're source-compatible buts BAs are not guaranteed binary-compatible.